# C# simple selection sort

Tags: c#, selection-sort

I'm trying to do selection sort for array. But for some reason it won't sort. My code:

```
public static void SelectionSort(DataArray ar)
    {
        int n = ar.Length;
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            int min_index = x;
            for (int y = x; y < n; y++)
            {
                if (ar[min_index] > ar[y])
                {
                    min_index = y;
                }
                ar.Swap(y, ar[x], ar[min_index]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any ideas and help.

My swap code looks like this

```
public override void Swap(int j, int a, int b) 
    { 
        data[j - 1] = a;
        data[j] = b; 
    }
```

Comment: can we see your swap method?, also consider making your question more explicit.

Comment: [Stack Overflow documentation of selection sort](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/algorithm/7473/selection-sort#t=201703072303190753508)

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, barring a few glitches. I did not compile but this should work.

```
public static void SelectionSort(DataArray ar)
{
    int n = ar.Length;
    for (int x = 0; x < n-1; x++)
    {
        int min_index = x;
        for (int y = x+1; y < n; y++)
        {
            if (ar[min_index] > ar[y])
            {
                min_index = y;
            }
            ar.Swap(y, ar[x], ar[min_index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arrayData = { 10,25,33,45,88,99,22,11,66,44,23};
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayData.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int minValue = i;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < arrayData.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arrayData[j] < arrayData[minValue])
                {
                    minValue = j;
                }

            }
            /*Swap Code*/
            int tempData = arrayData[minValue];
            arrayData[minValue] = arrayData[i];
            arrayData[i] = tempData;
        }

        /*Print Code*/
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayData.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(arrayData[i]+"\t");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use linq:

```
 var SortedArray = ar.OrderBy(o => o.Index).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Os. It doesn't answer the question because there isn't a question asked, but yes, it does fail to answer the question as a result of that.

Comment: @Servy true, the author of the question hasn't explicitly made his question stand out.

Comment: also we dont know that DataArray is an `IEnumerable<T>`